# DNS issues. Why and how to resolve?

Tags: networking, dns

I had been running internet via my USB modem and things were pretty well till last week. From then, I wasn't able to access websites or any net service, though applet shows network is connected. Earlier I thought its usual network's issue. But, when things escalate, I jump on to web through my mobile that is it just me?
As expected, it was with other people too and there are solutions too, one of which work for me.

But my question is,

1. Why is this happening?
2. I wasn't able to correct it by reconfiguring resolvconf. Why?
3. Presently, I have solved the issue by adding additional DNS in IPv4 settings (8.8.8.8,8.8.8.4). Now, since I am kind of security and privacy concious, I want to know that whether it means that all my traffic is routing through this DNS? If yes, then isn't t a privac and security issue.
4. How can I make things as good as before, i.e. accessing internet without using any additional DNS?

For others looking for a solution, here is which worked for me ["ping: unknown host google.com" but IP's works fine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/455338/no-internet-access-after-upgrading-from-ubuntu-12-04-to-ubuntu-14-04)

Regards

Answer (score 0):

No, you do not have to worry about security because you are using googles DNS sever, many people including myself use there servers because there server is faster then IP servers and are usually more reliable.

Comment: To know why your original dns is not working we would have to see how they where set up before, if you want to put it back the way it was you can  do what is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do>

Comment: I tried running that script, but it fails.
Here's the output: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7491359/

Comment: Yes, there is a file called wireless_script in home folder. Its output is here: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7491364/

Maybe this is what intended.

Comment: The file you are looking for in your home directory is wireless-info.txt or wireless-info.tar.gz