# Ubuntu 14.10 Network problems

Tags: wireless, networking, 14.10

I installed Ubuntu 14.10 a week ago. Everything was ok except some minor audio problems which I detailed in a previous post.

Currently as far as I can see networking is not working at all
- no wireless if I'm on Wi-Fi
- no Internet if I'm on cable
It also doesn't work in safe mode.

I tried most of the things I have seen on forums at network problems (changing failsafe config, changing networking config, etc). Currently I just left the first 2 lines for network config as described in this question: ["waiting for network configuration" Problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/213614/waiting-for-network-configuration-problem)

Comment: Can you tell us which network adapter you're using? Run `lspci | grep -i wlan` to see the available adapters.

Comment: @jessenorton Nothing happens if I run that command. However it worked until this afternoon. My laptop is this one: http://www.tlbhd.com/asus-n551jk-review-19227/

Comment: How about: lspci -nn | grep 0280 Thanks.

Comment: @chili555 This worked. I got 04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 [8086:08b1] (rev 6b)

Comment: Let's see if there are any errors in the log when you load the driver: sudo modprobe iwlwifi && dmesg | grep iwl If the output is lengthy, post it here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: @chili555 The output is longer than the text of the comment, but not that lengthy... Still. Here is the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com/8988289/

Comment: Looks pretty normal so far. How about iwconfig; dmesg | grep wlan. Paste as well, please.

Comment: Chat? http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18620/conversation-with-paxroman

Comment: @chili555 I am on chat now

Answer (score 1):

It worked after reinstalling resolvoncf, as described in this link: ["ping: unknown host google.com" but IP's works fine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/455338/ping-unknown-host-google-com-but-ips-works-fine)

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge resolvconf && sudo apt-get install --reinstall resolvconf
```

Thanks to @chilli555 for walking me through the first stages of the problem.

Comment: I see similar issues, but this didn't solve anything.

Comment: @Andy This is the solution if you are already connected to the network - so if you can check if you are connected to your network first, then if you run this command it should work.