# Removed resolvconf can't install anymore

Tags: 14.04, server, resolvconf

As stated in the title, I removed resolvconf (with reinstalling in mind because name resolution was acting up) but now I'm unable to install this package. 
I tried two things: 
apt-get install --reinstall resolvconf 
resulting in the following error:

> Package resolvconf is not available, but is referred to by another
>   package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been
>   obsoleted, or is only available from another source
>
> E: Package 'resolvconf' has no installation candidate

Using apt-get install resolvconf I get the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Test this:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
sudo -i
wget http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/r/resolvconf/resolvconf_1.69ubuntu1_all.deb
dpkg -i resolvconf_1.69ubuntu1_all.deb
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I actually changed archive.ubuntu.com with the actual ip and I got the package installed again!
wget http://91.189.91.13/ubuntu/pool/main/r/resolvconf/resolvconf_1.69ubuntu1_all.deb

Answer (score 4):

Grab the download URL domain:

```
$ sudo apt install resolvconf
...
E: Impossible de récupérer http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/r/resolvconf/resolvconf_1.78ubuntu2_all.deb
```

Resolve it manually using OpenDNS server (provided you have nslookup, otherwise use some [online DNS resolver](http://ping.eu/nslookup/)):

```
$ nslookup fr.archive.ubuntu.com 208.67.220.220
...
Non-authoritative answer:
Address: 194.158.119.190
```

Edit your hosts file:

```
$ gksudo gedit /etc/hosts &>/dev/null &
```

Add:

```
194.158.119.190 fr.archive.ubuntu.com
```

Retry to reinstall resolvconf:

```
$ sudo apt install resolvconf
```

Disconnect / reconnect your network from network-manager.

Test.

Remove the now useless entry from your hosts file.

Answer (score 0):

I manually downloaded this package:
http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/r/resolvconf/resolvconf_1.78ubuntu2_all.deb

Instead of this one (which was giving me a dependency error when *dpkg* it for Ubuntu 18.04):
http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/r/resolvconf/resolvconf_1.69ubuntu1_all.deb

My configuration is Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution.  You could enhance it by providing details of your configuration (Ubuntu xx.xx) or by explaining how you found that file.