# E: The package resolvconf needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it

Tags: apt, updates

When I use the command

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

then I get..

```
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package resolvconf needs to be reinstalled
```

Please, how do I resolve?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are having a dependency issue, so the following should solve that:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

`install -f` will solve dependency issues and help to fix broken packages.

**EDIT**

Try this to install the package:

```
cd
wget http://91.189.91.13/ubuntu/pool/main/r/resolvconf/resolvconf_1.69ubuntu1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i resolvconf_1.69ubuntu1_all.deb
```

This will download the package from a Ubuntu repository that has a DNS issue, hence the IP address rather than a domain name (source: [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/557303/175503))

Comment: Thank you...I have tried use command sudo apt-get install -f, and I get...Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package resolvconf needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.

Comment: Thank you...I have tried use command sudo apt-get install -f, and I get...Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree Reading state information... Done E: The package resolvconf needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it. How to resolve it?

Comment: @AriesDS I updated my answer with some more info that may help

Comment: When I use....cd
wget http://91.189.91.13/ubuntu/pool/main/r/resolvconf/resolvconf_1.69ubuntu1_all. I got ....Connecting to 91.189.91.13:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.  How should I resolve?