# ubuntu recognize huawei E8231 usb-wifi but the internet not working

Tags: networking, usb, internet, huawei

i got this problem with huawei usb-wifi and i can't find any solution since two days. if you can help or guide me that would be great.
two days ago , i bought huawei E8231 usb-wifi from vodafone but when i try to connect it with ubuntu , the following scenarios happened:

1. when i connect the stick to power adapter , wifi works perfectly and i am able to connect the internet from android phone and laptop windows.ubuntu connects to the wifi but internet doesn't work (doesn't load any page) but i can load configuration page through the browser 192.168.8.1
2. when i plug the stick to usb port on my laptop:
   in windows , the internect works perfectly and it appear as LAN caple connected to laptop.
   in ubuntu , a notification appear saying

> connection established. you are now connected to 'wired connection 2'

but when i load a web page it doesn't load but configuration page load perfectly.

if anyone can help with that or guide me , that will be great because it's been two days in real pain.
thanks

Comment: For modems that emulate Ethernet you usually need to use its own web interface to setup and/or connect. Open its IP address, the same as in "gateway", in any browser and follow instructions.

Comment: this device doesn't require any set up , it's connecting perfectly from windows and android without any configuration. besides , when i open gateway ip , it have only some settings related to usage statics and wifi password.

Comment: Does it show as connected?

Comment: yes , and a notification appears on the top right of the screen saying "connection established. you are now connected to 'wired connection 2'"

Comment: Yes, of course the Ethernet is connected - you already told us so -. I'm asking about the mobile connection: When you opened its web interface did it show as connected or not?

Comment: yes, it shows it's connected and statics data are increased (some bytes or kb) . of course when i connect an android device through wifi and browse  from mobile i see statics are increased.

Comment: OK, now please check http://askubuntu.com/questions/455338/ping-unknown-host-google-com-but-ips-works-fine as it may well be the same situation. If `ping 8.8.8.8` is successful but `ping google.com` isn't you may need to follow the suggestions there.

Comment: exactly , it was a DNS problem. thanks a lot for your help. 
i solved it by putting `nameserver 8.8.8.8` on `/etc/resolv.conf`. 
i thought about dns before but i didn't search too much about it because i checked dns on android and connection configuration on ubuntu and the dns was the same "192.168.8.1" (i forgot to check main dns file on ubuntu - /etc/resolv.conf) but when you mentioned ping , that helped me a lot.
thanks a gain for your help and thanks for your time

Comment: You're welcome. If you want you can actually make it into an answer (and accept it). Give me a nudge and I upvote it.

Comment: ok , kindly put it as an answer and i will choose it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
connection established. you are now connected to 'wired connection 2'
```

The above means the device was correctly identified and is working as expected via an emulated Ethernet connection.

Knowing that it is also connected to the mobile network as evidenced by other devices using its own WiFi AP as well as the modem's web interface showing a functional internet connection, then it must be a DNS problem. In order to correct this please edit `/etc/resolv.conf`  and add `nameserver 8.8.8.8`.