# Cannot access internet on Terminal, browser works fine

Tags: command-line, networking, internet, proxy

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and connected to network through Ethernet. I am able to browse and connect to Internet via browser but having issue through terminal.
I tried to ping www.google.com from terminal there is no response but through browser i can open the web-page.
I am not able use apt-get as well. When gave apt-get Update, for a longtime there is no response and then it says unable to connect. Even in ubuntu software center the problem exist. The cache wont update it says querying for long time and then just closes.

I have made sure following

1. LAN is connected
2. Proxy settings are done in browser and system settings
3. I am using office network
4. Able to connect to Internet via Mozilla firefox

Any suggestions anything i am missing.

Comment: what is the result of `ping 8.8.8.8` ?

Comment: I suspect that your problem is related to DNS (i.e. you have connectivity to IP numbers, but the computer doesn't handle correctly host-names)

Comment: The result of ping 8.8.8.8 
kb@DS-2144AA006430:~$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.

I am on Office network so don't have much control. And not able to point the issue as well.

Comment: I am able to ping my proxy servers, i am getting reply from it.

Comment: please [edit] your question with the result of `traceroute 8.8.8.8`

Comment: take a look at this [Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/q/455338/544264) and this [Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/q/368435/544264)